# Understanding Number.toString(radix) unexpected token exception

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to understand difference between `4` and `(4)`.

```js
4.toString(); // SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL

(4).toString(); // "4"
```

I thought it's because `toString()` method is defined on `Number` (object) and 4 is a primitive datatype i.e.`number` which doesn't have `toString()` method.

However, how does it works for `(4).toString()`?

```js
4 === (new Number(4)) // false
(4) === (new Number(4)) // false. (4) is not an instance of Number object
```

Comment: Dot (`.`) doesn't only means for member access operator, it also means for decimal point in [floating-point literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Grammar_and_types#Floating-point_literals). When JS interpreter meet dot after digit (`4` in your case) it expects floating-point literal, i.e. digits after dot. That's why do you need grouping operator (parens) there.

Comment: @hindmost thank you, It makes sense now. Can you please put this comment as an answer?

Comment: space works too: `alert( 123 .toString(36))`

Comment: As does a second dot, e.g. `4..toString()`. (The first one is a decimal point; the second one is a member access.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dot (`.`) doesn't only means for member access operator. It also means for decimal point in [floating-point literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Grammar_and_types#Floating-point_literals). When JS interpreter meets dot after digit (`4` in your case) it expects floating-point literal, i.e. digits after dot. That's why do you need grouping operator (parens) there.